# Attach RepeatedType validation error to field, not to form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a `FormBuilder`:

```
$builder
            ->add(
                'token',
                Type\TextType::class,
                array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'trim' => true,
                    'attr' => array(),
                    'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(array('message' => 'password.notBlank')))
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'password',
                Type\RepeatedType::class,
                array(
                    'type' => Type\PasswordType::class,
                    'required' => true,
                    'invalid_message' => 'password.notMatch',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        new Assert\NotBlank(array('message' => 'password.notBlank')),
                        new Assert\Length(
                            array(
                                'min' => 8,
                                'max' => 40,
                                'minMessage' => 'password.lengthMin',
                                'maxMessage' => 'password.lengthMax',
                            )
                        ),
                    )
                )
            );
```

The problem is that `token` field is attached to particular field so I can get the error object via:

```
 foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
            foreach ($child->getErrors() as $key => $error) ...
```

but `password` is attached to form itself, so the only way how I can get the error is:

```
$errors = $form->getErrors(true, false);
```

which doesn't give me any field description info.. How can I override such behavior?